# When & That difference

Tags: word-choice, relative-pronouns

A man and a woman are talking on the phone:

> I'm sorry, but can you please cancel my appointment for today?
> Sure thing.
> **Is there another day when you can come in?**
> How about Saturday? The morning is better for me.

What is the difference between the two sentences?
1-) Is there another day **when** you can come in ?
2-) Is there another day **that** you can come in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A native speaker could use either of those sentences. "Is there another day **when** you can come in?" has better grammar. In fact, the other one is bad grammar, but it's commonly used by native speakers.

Sentence 1: A *relative clause* with "**when**" describes a noun by using that noun in an *adverbial of time*. In this case, the deeper structure of the sentence is:

> "Is there another day?" + "You can come in **on that day**."

The pronoun "when" replaces the *adverbial* "on that day". "Day" refers to the same "day" as earlier in the sentence.

Sentence 2: A *relative clause* with "**that**" describes a noun by using it as a subject or an object in another sentence. The grammar doesn't work here, because "You can come in" already has a subject, "you", and there's no place for an object. The word "in" is part of the phrasal verb "come in", not a preposition, so it cannot take an object. "...**that** you can come in" suggests a deeper structure like:

> *"Is there another day?" + "You can come in **day**."

which is nonsense. One way to fix this is to add the preposition "on" to the end:

> "Is there another day that you can come in on?"

You can come in *on a day*, so this is good grammar.